# What to do with wasabi flowering?

Tags: flowers, growth, propagation

I'm trying to grow wasabi for the first time. The plant seems to be doing well and has produced several flowers (on long snaking stems).

I'm not sure what to do with them. I know some plants grow better if you cut off the flowers (some even die if you don't). Is wasabi one of these? should I cut them off or let them go? Presumably they'd make seeds for propagating? but I think wasabi makes off-plants anyway for propagation, which would probably be easier and quicker.

So what is recommended to do with them?